# Roots of a complex number equation

Tags: complex-numbers

$i)$ It is given that $-1 + \sqrt {5} i$ is a root of the equation $z^3 + 2z + a = 0$, where $a$ is real. Showing your working, find the value of $a$, and write down the other complex root of this equation.

$ii)$ The complex number $w$ has a modulus 1 and argument $2\theta$ radians. Show that $\frac {w - 1}{w + 1} = itan\theta$.

Im completely stuck in both of them, for part $i)$ how do I go about solving this type of question?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_conjugate_root_theorem

Comment: If $u$ is a complex root of a real equation so is $\overline u$. That gives you two roots. What's the other one?

Comment: Do you know Vieta's formulas?

Comment: For future reference it is undesirable to post unrelated problems together in one Question.  Math.SE undertakes to help learners of math at all levels, but not to be a do-your-thinking-for-you site.  Focus on explaining one problem at a time, and give more context than "I'm completely stuck".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For part $i$, you could do it this way:

If $x+iy$ is a solution of a real polynomial, then so is $x-iy$, by the theorem given in the comments. So in this case, $-1+\sqrt5i$ and $-1-\sqrt5i$ are roots. $$(z+1-\sqrt5i)(z+1+\sqrt5i)=z^2+2z+6$$
You know that this times something else gives the equation they have. So $$z^3+2z+a\equiv(z-z_0)(z^2+2z+6)$$ 
You can then solve this by comparing coefficients (spoiler below):

> $$\implies z_0=2\implies a=-12$$

For part $ii$, DonAntonio's method is the same as I'd use, so I won't repeat that.

Answer (score 2):

Hints:

$$0=(-1+\sqrt5\,i)^3+2(-1+\sqrt5\,i)+a=-5\sqrt5i+15+3\sqrt5\,i-1-2+2\sqrt5\,i+a=\ldots$$

For the other one

$$w=e^{2i\theta}\implies\frac{w-1}{w+1}=\frac{(w-1)(\overline w+1)}{|w+1|^2}=\frac{2\sin2\theta}{2(\cos2\theta+1)}i=\ldots$$

a little trigonometric identities finish the business.

Answer (score 0):

In order that all coefficients be real, along with solution a+ bi, its complez conjugate, a- bi, must also be a root.  In order that a cubic equation, with all real coefficients have $1+ i\sqrt{5}$, $1- i\sqrt{5}$ must also be a root.  If we call the third root (which must be real) "u" then the cubic must be $(z- 1- i\sqrt{5}(z- 1+ i\sqrt{5})(z- u)$.  The easy way to multiply the first two terms is to right them as $((z-1)- i\sqrt{5})((z- 1)+ \sqrt{5})$ and use the fact that $(a+ b)(a- b)= a^2- b^2$.  Here, that gives $(z- 1)^2- (-1)5= z^2- 2z+ 6$.

Multiplying that by the third factor, z- u, we have $z^3- 2z^2+ 6z- uz^2- 2uz+ 6u= z^3- (2+ u)z^2+ (6+ 2u)z+ 6u$.  Comparing that to $z^3+ 2z+ a$ we must have -(2+ u)= 0 so that u= -2. That makes a= 6u= 6(-2)= -12.